Enumerate triple sort operations for sorting a given array
I'm trying to solve the following challenge:

Given length n and an array with n values, enumerate the 'Triple' operations that make the array sorted.
The 'Triple' operation is described as follows:
For 3 indices 1≤i<j<k≤n the minimum is stored in A[i], the middle one in A[j] and the greatest in A[k].
You have to print the number of Triple operations and the i, j, and k for each operation.
Examples:
input:
5
5 2 3 1 4  

output:
2  
1 2 4  
3 4 5

input:
9  
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  

output:
4  
1 5 9  
2 5 8  
3 5 7  
4 5 6

The array changes as follows:
⟨9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1⟩ → ⟨1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,9⟩ → ⟨1,2,7,6,5,4,3,8,9⟩ → ⟨1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9⟩ → ⟨1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9⟩
Note that the number of operations doesn't have to be minimum and it is guaranteed that the array can be sorted in such way
Constraints:

3 ≤ n ≤ 105
10-9 ≤ a[i] ≤ 109


I tried to sort the array and attain each index by making an inversion function that returns the index of a wanted element, but that doesn't work since the array can have repeated elements like A = 3 2 3 1 where 3 is repeated.
Another brute force approach was to put the minimum of the remaining array in its right place but this makes the algorithm to be O(n²) which is not suitable.
How can I make it work also with repeated values?

You can use a balanced binary search tree to maintain the elements of the remaining part of the array in order.

Sorting the list first seems like a good idea. What you actually would want to have, is the index sequence of what would represent the sorted order. You could for instance use numpy.argsort to get that.
This will give you one ore more cycles (circular singly linked lists) if you would follow the "links" that these index references represent. An idea would be to take such a cycle, and use a triple operation to move the final value to the leftmost index of that cycle, and update the cycle accordingly, so that it will be one node shorter. This removal is not very efficient if you only have the above mentioned singly circular linked lists. It will be better to build a doubly circular linked list from each.
There are then a few boundary conditions to take into account:

We arrive at an index that has a self reference (a linked list with just one element): this means the value is already at its sorted position and there is nothing to do.

We arrive at an index that is part of a cycle of 2. In that case we need to find a third value we can use to execute a Triple operation in such a way that only this cycle of 2 is resolved (a swap), and that third value stays where it is. If some values were already placed at their final index, you can use one of those. If not, you can delay the work on this cycle of 2, and resolve it later, either when you have a second cycle of 2, or a value that has reached its final destination. Two cycles of 2 can be sorted with two executions of the Triple operation.

We arrive at an index that is part of a cycle that has a size of at least 3. This could be seen as the generic case. One execution of the Triple operation can put at least one value at its final spot, and shorten the rest of the cycle.


The number of Triple executions will be O() with this algorithm. The overal time complexity is determined by getting the indices of the values in sorted order, and is O(log).
Below is an implementation. Be aware that it uses 0-based indexing, so to use it for the code challenge (which uses 1-based indexing), you'll need to add one to each index in the list of resulting triples, as you output them.
import numpy as np  # Only used for argsort

# Main algorithm
def get_triples(lst):
    if len(lst) == 2 and lst[0] > lst[1]:  # Boundary case (excluded by the challenge)
        raise ValueError("Cannot sort this list with Triple operations")

    triples = []  # The list op Triple operations to be returned by this function

    # Build doubly circular linked lists, representing the sort order:
    # Get indexes of where values should be taken from to get a sorted result
    takefrom = np.argsort(lst)
    # Opposite: Get indexes of where current values should be moved to, to get a sorted result
    bringto = [0] * len(lst)
    for target, source in enumerate(takefrom):
        bringto[source] = target


    def triple(i, j, k):
        i, j, k = sorted([i, j, k])
        # Collect this operation
        triples.append((i, j, k))
        # Update takenfrom and bringto as a result of this triple operation:  
        bringto[i], bringto[j], bringto[k] = sorted([bringto[i], bringto[j], bringto[k]])
        for m in i, j, k:
            takefrom[bringto[m]] = m


    index_done = -1  # Index which already contains the value it should get in the sorted result 
    cycle_of_2 = None   # Pair of indices which should get their values swapped using a safe third participant
    for a, (b, c) in enumerate(zip(takefrom, bringto)):
        if b != c:  # Are a,b,c in a cycle larger than 2?
            triple(a, b, c)
        elif b < a:  # Is this the second index of a delayed cycle-of-2?
            continue  # Ignore
        elif a == b:  # Is this an index that already has its sorted value? (Not a cycle of 2, but 1)
            pass
        elif cycle_of_2:  # Do we have another cycle of 2 that is pending?
            # Combine and resolve both cycles of 2:
            x, y = cycle_of_2
            triple(x, y, a)  # This puts the final value at index x
            triple(y, a, b)  # This puts the final values at y, a, and b 
            cycle_of_2 = None
        elif index_done == -1:  # Do we lack an index that could serve as dummy participant in triple?
            cycle_of_2 = a, b  # Remember this cycle of 2 for later resolution
            continue  # Do not update index_done
        else: # We can use index_done as dummy participant in a call of triple
            triple(index_done, a, b)
        index_done = a
        if cycle_of_2:
            # We can use index_done as dummy participant in a call of triple
            triple(index_done, *cycle_of_2)
            cycle_of_2 = None

    return triples

The above function will return a list of triple operations that would sort the given list if executed on it.
Here is a helper function to verify that this is indeed the case:
def apply_triples(lst, triples):
    for i, j, k in triples:
        assert i < j < k
        lst[i], lst[j], lst[k] = sorted([lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]])
    assert lst == sorted(lst)

And finally a script to test on several lists:
import itertools
import random

# Test on all permuations of a list of size 6
for lst in map(list, itertools.permutations([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])):
    apply_triples(lst, get_triples(lst))

# Test on large random list
lst = list(range(100000))
random.shuffle(lst)
apply_triples(lst, get_triples(lst))

print("test completed")

